# Push notification without client application installed

Tags: android, firebase, web, push-notification

we have a web application using responsible html, it is seamlesly usable from mobile browsers...

We would like to send "event" (push notification) to users phones (device!). Standard notification with icon of our app and short text. Pending intent would be just open our web application in browser (URL).

So, question is how to do this without need of client application installed on target phone which would provide registration of such device (send it to our server, who will use it later to let firebase to notify such device).

Is it possible to create a **device** registration from browser (chrome)? Either to google account used in device or ask to fill it ...

How are web notification related? If I understood it correctly, a page with our app needs to be opened to receive web notification. What about instant apps?

Yeah, we could create a very simple application which would be linked (google play) from our web application - which would provide JUST registration a receiving of push notification. And than just open a browser. But it looks to me as unnecessary, because push client is part of android system. The only what we need to send device ID to our server...

Thanks for any idea. Ideally, a link to documentation or proof-of-concept on github (-: because I believe it is a standart situation.

PS: And sure, as always, at the end we would like to have it multi platform. And no, we prefer not to use non-system providers like pushy ...

Comment: I think you need to use web push notifications in your web app with FCM. Not sure if the notification works when the page is open or not. 
Also the UI of the notification will be based on the browser.

Comment: See the documentation here for web notifications : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/first-message